# Magento 2 - When I run any command it gives me error

Tags: magento-2.1, cli, command

`php -f bin/magento cache:flush`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Commands giving this error.Please check this, https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-error For more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

Comment: Please edit **/etc/php/<PHP_version>/apache2/php.ini**. and set `memory_limit = -1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run below command:

**Static content deploy:**

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Cache flush:**

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Setup Upgrade:**

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Now problem is when i enter any command.is not proceeding any actions

Comment: Try increasing the limit in your php.ini.` memory_limit = -1`

Answer (score 0):

php -dmemory_limit=6G great this is working now .. i can run commands thanks